# Installing custom packages on Linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, package-management

I am currently using Kali, sometimes clean Debian, and sometimes I want to install a package, which is not on my sources list. And you can't find those, and add to sources file. I mean f.e I download the newest Python, which is `3.5.2`, and on my OS there is Python `3.4.3`. So I unpack the package and here's a question. Where should I put it and then go for `./configure` then `./make install`? I mean in which directory, like : `/etc`, `/home`? When I was installing Linux I've chosen just to make separate `swap` and `/home` partition.

P.S Should I maybe use something like : `software-center`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update Python, why don't you use your distro's package manager?  `apt-get` in the case of Debian.

If you want to install a different version of python, it would be best to do that in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

If you're installing a package you're building, usually it would be placed somewhere like `/usr/local/bin`.

You'll find most of your currently installed binaries are in somewhere like `/usr/bin`, but generally you don't want to install there.

If you want to install just for the current user, then create a bin directory and add it to your path within the user's home directory

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

For the source files, create a directory for those like `~/src` anywhere you like.